# Does the following series converge or diverge: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Which of the following series converge, and which diverge?

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n}}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}}$

**MY ATTEMPT**

The first one converges due to the comparison test. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+1} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}
\end{align*}
where the last series is the $p$-series with $p = 2 > 1$.

The second series does converge due to the ratio test. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\times\frac{n^{n}}{n!} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n} = e^{-1} < 1
\end{align*}

Finally, for the third series it suffices to notice that $n^{2} + n \leq 2n^{2}$. Thence we conclude that it diverges. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow +\infty
\end{align*}

Is the wording of my solutions good? Any comments and contributions are appreciated.

Comment: Seems legit to me.

Comment: Yep, looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is correct and well-worded. Where you have used the phrase "harmonic series with $p = 2$", you really should say "$p$-series with $p = 2$. The harmonic series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$, whereas $p$-series are series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$.

Comment: I would have called the comparison series used in the first one a "p-series".  I reserve "harmonic series" for the special case of $p=1$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Good call; I missed that. Why not edit in the correction? It is community wiki after all.

Comment: @JasonDeVito thanks for the comment. I haved edited my answer in order to include your suggestion.

Comment: @BrickByBrick The so-called p-series (dumb name) is also called the hyperharmonic series.

Comment: I understand that StackExchange encourages editting of others people's work, but I just don't really like to do it, especially when it comes to changing the content (as opposed to simple grammar/spelling edits.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I guessed that, so I edited it instead. I agree with non-CW answers, but the point of CW answers is that it's just as much my answer as anyone else's. Besides, my original answer barely qualified as "work". :-)